# Select * faster than JSONB field lookup Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgres 9.5.3, I have a table with ~10k text documents.  One of the fields `content` is JSONB, whose entries tend to look like this:

```
{'title' : 'Short Document Title', 'text' : 'Some loooooong text......'}
```

A simple select * and sort query works fine:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM documents
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 25;

    Limit  (cost=2224.60..2224.67 rows=25 width=1393) (actual time=30.733..30.741 rows=25 loops=1)
       ->  Sort  (cost=2224.60..2246.16 rows=8624 width=1393) (actual time=30.731..30.733 rows=25 loops=1)
             Sort Key: release_date DESC
             Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 65kB
             ->  Seq Scan on document  (cost=0.00..1981.24 rows=8624 width=1393) (actual time=0.025..26.463 rows=8624 loops=1)
     Planning time: 0.388 ms
     Execution time: 30.840 ms
```

However, with a single JSONB field lookup, the execution time increases over 30x:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT content->'title'
FROM documents
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 25;

Limit  (cost=2246.16..2246.23 rows=25 width=59) (actual time=972.382..972.389 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=2246.16..2267.72 rows=8624 width=59) (actual time=972.380..972.382 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: release_date DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
         ->  Seq Scan on document  (cost=0.00..2002.80 rows=8624 width=59) (actual time=0.582..964.898 rows=8624 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.114 ms
 Execution time: 972.434 ms
```

Why is the second query so much slower / what should be done to improve its performance (preferably aside from changing the schema)?

**Update:**  I've upgraded from 9.5.3 > 10.1 expecting to see better performance.  In fact the performance on 10.1 is equivalently bad:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT content->'title'
FROM documents
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 25;

 Limit  (cost=2009.16..2009.23 rows=25 width=36) (actual time=1011.282..1011.288 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=2009.16..2030.72 rows=8624 width=36) (actual time=1011.281..1011.285 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: release_date DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 30kB
         ->  Seq Scan on documents  (cost=0.00..1765.80 rows=8624 width=36) (actual time=0.157..1005.157 rows=8624 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.090 ms
 Execution time: 1011.315 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because you are using a PostgreSQL version older than 9.6.

In the [9.6 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-6.html#idm46428656695344) you can see the relevant entry:

> - When appropriate, postpone evaluation of `SELECT` output expressions until after an `ORDER BY` sort (Konstantin Knizhnik)
>
>   This change ensures that volatile or expensive functions in the output list are executed in the order suggested by `ORDER BY`, and that they are not evaluated more times than required when there is a `LIMIT` clause. Previously, these properties held if the ordering was performed by an index scan or pre-merge-join sort, but not if it was performed by a top-level sort.

The `jsonb` values are not stored in the main table, but in the *[TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) table* that belongs to it. If the value is accessed, it has to be “detoasted”, that is loaded from the TOAST table and uncompressed.

In your first query, this only happens with the 25 rows that are returned to the client, but in the second query, all 8624 `jsonb` values get detoasted.

Comment: Thanks. In case others run into this who are stuck on 9.5, a quick workaround is to rewrite with a subquery:  SELECT content->'title' FROM (SELECT * FROM documents ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 25) as temp